# woocommerce_admin is not defined

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, console, referenceerror, uncaught-reference-error

I am getting one error in wordpress admin console - " Uncaught ReferenceError: woocommerce_admin is not defined "

I can't figure it out why I am getting this error.

Wordpress version - 5.9
WooCommerce version - 6.4.1

Comment: Try disabling all other plugins except WooCommerce